# Macro-enabled Excel Workbook Crashing on Open: What does 'ForceVBALoadFromSource' Actually Do?

Tags: excel, vba, registry

I'm having a recurring issue with a macro-enabled workbook hosted on SharePoint that is accessed by multiple users. As the workbook_open sub runs, the Excel process is either killed or hangs on an error message. I did some searching and found the fix of adding registry values ForceVBALoadFromSource (DWORD, 1) and CompileOnDemand (DWORD, 0)

I've noticed that just adding ForceVBALoadFromSource fixes the issue, so I made only that change, and did not add CompileOnDemand.

I've gathered that the CompileOnDemand registry value is the same as going into General Options in the VBE and disabling "Compile On Demand", which forces the entire project to be recompiled before running, and not just any parts that were changed.

However, I'm not exactly sure what "ForceVBALoadFromSource" is doing, which I'd like to know before I'm comfortable distributing this fix to multiple people. So far, I've only seen general answers that it's forcing a recompile. Maybe I'm being mislead by the name, but what does "Source" refer to, and what would be the alternative to loading from "Source"?

Also, for anyone familiar, should changes to both ForceVBALoadFromSource and CompileOnDemand be added together, or am I just good with the ForceVBALoadFromSource change?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if it's related, but there's a *Compile On Demand* option in VBE which is enabled by default. (Options/General)